# How to suspend GDB run using python and pygdbmi library

Tags: python, arm, gdb

I am writing python script to debug an embedded software running on an ARM chip.

To do so, I use pygdbmi python library. This library let me configure and launch my script but there is one feature I can't find: I don't find a way to suspend the execution of my program.

I want to execute the software I debug for a certain amount of time (let say 1 second) before suspending it to check global variables values, etc. To do so, I wanted to send "continue" to gdb to run my program, then sleep for 1 second and finally send "-exec-interrupt" to suspend the program and send new commands to gdb.

Here is the part of the source code I use for that :

```
gdbmi = GdbController("arm-none-eabi-gdb")
# swPath is the path to my software binary
gdbmi.write('-file-exec-and-symbols %s' % swPath)
# I have to connect to an openOCD server
gdbmi.write('tar rem :3333') 
gdbmi.write('monitor reset halt')
gdbmi.write('load')
gdbmi.write('c')
time.sleep(1)
gdbmi.write('-exec-interrupt')
```

When I execute this python script, I have the following error raised:

```
raise GdbTimeoutError('Did not get response from gdb after %s seconds' % timeout_sec)
pygdbmi.gdbcontroller.GdbTimeoutError: Did not get response from gdb after 1 seconds
```

So it seems that I can't write a new command to gdb when the debugged software is running.

How am I supposed to suspend my software ? When I use GDB manually, I do this by sending Ctrl-C signal (SIGINT), and I'd like to do the same from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I'm the developer of `pygdbmi`.

You can do

```
import os

# create gdbmi instance

os.kill(gdbmi.gdb_process.pid, 2)  # sends signal 2 (SIGINT) to gdb
```

I'd like to add a way to do this with a new method such as `send_signal_to_gdb`.

I created an issue on the github page and will add these methods in the next release: https://github.com/cs01/pygdbmi/issues/26.